# How to reset the index in .each function to keep calling it again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented my own slide show in jQuery, things are working fine for the first one iteration where I am stuck is when the function completes it iteration over all the images once how restart it back from the first and keep running this process again and again.

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
var slides = $('#contain').children('div');
console.log(slides.length);
slides.each(function (i, v) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var slide = $(v);
        console.log(i + "-" + v);
        $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide.find('img').attr('src')).fadeIn(interval * 100);
        $('#slideDesc').html(slide.find('span').html()).fadeIn(interval * 100);
    }, i * interval * 1000);
});

//startSlideShow(interval);
}
```

I tried calling it recursively but didn't work and hangs the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function startSlideShow(interval) {
    var slides = $('#contain').children('div');
    var idx = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var slide = slides.eq(idx++);
            $('#currentImage').attr('src', slide.find('img').attr('src')).fadeIn(interval * 100);
            $('#slideDesc').html(slide.find('span').html()).fadeIn(interval * 100);
            idx = idx % slides.length;
    }, 1000 * interval)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L6F4S/)

Comment: works perfect. but can you explain me for me for my understanding what is happening on this line `idx = idx % slides.length;` ?

Comment: `%` = modulus (remainder of division). So, `idx % slides.length;` returns a number which is the remainder of `idx / slides.length`. That way idx is always a number between 0 and slides.length.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting timeouts into the future, one for each image. The only way to make this keep working is to set another timeout in `slides.length * interval * 1000` to re-set the timeouts. Lots of timeouts.

This is not a particularly good way of doing things. The timeouts aren't exact and won't line up completely accurately, especially if you make it run a long time.

Better is to set one timeout, and at the end of the function set another. This will run the function (approximately) every `n` milliseconds. You can increment a counter each time round and then reset it when it reaches `slides.length`.

E.g.

```
var counter = 0;

var handler = function() {
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == slides.length) { counter = 0; }

    // Show slide 'counter'

    setTimeout(handler, interval * 1000);
}

handler();
```